# send POST request using JS

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I've got a trouble with sending POST request. I'm trying to like any quote at bash.im site. I looked at source code and found that when I click like button, JS send POST request with following structure:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: s[sid]+qid+'/'+ms[m],
    data:'quote='+qid+'&act='+ms[m],
    success: function(){
        ...
    }
```

where url is something like "/quote/123/like" and data is "quote=123&act=like"

I wrote code in JS that must emulate that request, but it doesn't work (count of likes at site doesn't changing):

```
var params = "quote=123&act=rulez"


xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xmlhttp.open('POST', "http://bash.im/quote/123/rulez", true)

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("rate "+xmlhttp.readyState+" "+xmlhttp.status)
}
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
xmlhttp.send(params)
```

console output:

```
rate 2 200
rate 3 200
rate 4 200
```

What I'm doing wrong?